# How to enable `relevance-trace` using MarkLogic Java API?

Tags: java, marklogic

I'm implementing quite a complex search using MarkLogic Java API. I would like to enable `relevance-trace` ([Relavance trace](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_52452)) to see how my results are scored. Unfortunately, I don't know how to enable it in Java API. I have tried something like:

```
    DatabaseClient client = initClient();
    var qmo = client.newServerConfigManager().newQueryOptionsManager();
    var searchOptions = "<search:options xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">\n"
        + "    <search-option>relevance-trace</search-option>\n"
        + "  </search:options>";
    qmo.writeOptions("searchOptions", new StringHandle(searchOptions).withFormat(Format.XML));
    QueryManager qm = client.newQueryManager();
    StructuredQueryBuilder qb = qm.newStructuredQueryBuilder("searchOptions");
    
    // query definition

    qm.search(query, new SearchHandle())
```

Unfortunately it ends up with following error:

```
   "Local message: /config/query write failed: Internal Server Error. Server Message: XDMP-DOCNONSBIND: 
   xdmp:get-request-body(\"xml\") -- No namespace binding for prefix search at  line 1 . See the 
   MarkLogic server error log for further detail."
```

My question is how to use search options in MarkLogic API, especially I'm interested in `relevance-trace` and `simple-score`

**Update 1**

As suggested by @Jamess Kerr I have change my options to

```
    var searchOptions = "<options xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">\n"
        + "    <search-option>relevance-trace</search-option>\n"
        + "  </options>";
```

but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. After that change I get error:

```
   Local message: /config/query write failed: Internal Server Error. Server Message: XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY: xdmp:apply(function() as item()*) -- Cannot apply an update function from a query . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your search options XML uses the `search:` namespace prefix but you don't define that prefix. Since you are setting the default namespace, just drop the `search:` prefix from the `search:options` open and close tags.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, unfortunately it haven't helped much. See Update 1 in my question.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the QueryOptionsManager.write() implementation. Feel free to log an issue on the GitHub repository with steps for reproducing the issue.  As a workaround, consider sending the search criteria and query options in a single request with a combined search, as described here:  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_76144

Answer (score 0):

The original Java Query contains both syntactical and semantic issues:

> First of all, it is an invalid MarkLogic XQuery in the sense that it has only query option(s) portion. Bypassing the namespace binding prefix is another wrong end of the stick.

> To tweak your original query, please replace a search text in between the search:qtext tag ( the pink line ) and run the query.
> [image]

Result:

```
Matched and Listing 2 documents:

Matched 1 locations in /medals/coin_1333113127296.xml with 94720 score:
73. …pulsating maple leaf coin another world-first, the [Royal Canadian Mint]is proud to launch a numismatic breakthrough from its ambitious and creative R&D team...
Matched 1 locations in /medals/coin_1333078361643.xml with 94720 score:
71. ...the [Royal Canadian Mint]and Royal Australian Mint have put an end to the dispute relating to the circulation coin colouring process...
```

> Without a semantic criterion, to put it into context, your original query will be an equivalent of removing the `search:qtext` and performing a fuzzy search.

> Note:
>
> If you use serialised term search or search constraints instead of text search, you should get higher score results.
>
> MarkLogic Java API operates in `unfiltered` mode by default, while the `cts:search` operates in `filtered` mode by default.  Just be mindful of how you construct the query and the expected score in Java API.
> And it is really intended for bulk data write/extract/transformation.  qconsole is, in my opinion, more befitting to tune specific query and gather search score, relevance and computation details.

Comment: Hi Fiona, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't know how to apply your answer on my code. Can you tell me what exactly should I change in my code?